# Getting average or number of columns Highstock

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm working with Highstock Column chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/column/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        }]
    });
```

When we change range to bigger on the navigator it joins bars and its values. Is there any way to getting average of these two values, not the sum?

Or, is there a possibility to get an amount of columns, that are visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled in the [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) options. At the link it tells you what the default calculation is for `approximation`:

> Defaults to average for line-type series, sum for columns, range for
>   range series and ohlc for OHLC and candlestick.

You can change this to `'average'` for your column data.

Comment: Thank U! I mean "average", but ok ;)

Comment: @user3541098, fixed my fat finger mistake.